# Is there a way to spoof a desktop browser response to a css media query?

Tags: mobile, browser, css, media-queries

Maybe a browser plugin?  Just looking for a dirty, quick way to test some mobile web development.

Comment: It depends on the particular media query..

Comment: Pixel density, Device Width, Device Height, Resolution.

Comment: do you want to test for like what css rules are getting triggered? what kind of tests are u looking to perform?

Comment: [Mobile Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cllkoedgiefnomcccogcalmjogjfcpji) for Chrome. There are actually quite a few extensions to handle width/height, but not sure about density/resolution apart from downloading the latest Android/iOS emulators.

Comment: What @cchana said.  Here is an alternative - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's 3 tools I found pretty helpful for testing media queries for mobile devices within my desktop browser:

1. [Adobe Shadow](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/): You'll have to download the app on your mobile device, and then link the device to Chrome and once you've done so you can inspect your webpages on chrome as they would appear on your mobile device.
2. [Remote Debugging with Chrome for Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging): Similar to Adobe Shadow, but I found this to be a lot more reliable when dealing with network requests on mobile devices - you will need a android device with Ice Cream Sandwich however.
3. [Changing User Agent on Safari to debug different browsers straight from your desktop Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/PrototypingYourWebsite/PrototypingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH7-SW11): If you have Safari, it allows you to change the useragent string from the developer tools. Pretty useful if you want to spoof browsers. - Didn't really find this useful for media queries though.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Safari settings, there is one that reads "Request Desktop Website." Check it, then browse to facebook.com Now you can message within browser. No app needed.